# How do you use (何, 誰, etc) + the verb in ようform + と

Tags: grammar, translation, usage

I was reading some sentences in japanese to practice and I came across this sentence:

> 何を好きになろうと、誰と話そうと

According to google traslator it means something like: "no matter what you like or who you talk to"

If the translation is right, what would be the difference between that and (何,誰,etc)+the verb in て form+も

For example:

> 誰と話そうと
> 誰と話しても

Please keep in mind I'm a beginner, thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27604/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28939/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32949/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48292/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean the same thing, but ～ようと is more literary in style, while ～ても is relatively colloquial. The difference is not very big, and mature adults use both in speech, but the more formal the situation is, the more often ～ようと is chosen. There is also ～ようが, which is slightly more emphatic than ～ようと.

See also:

- [Meaning of volitional passive form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32949/5010)
- [What are the grammar rules behind this clause, 「才能があろうがなかろうが」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48292/5010)
- JGram: [(よ)うが (よ)うと ようが ようと](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=(yo)uga%2C(yo)uto)